# Text-box value does not change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am generating textbox in MVC Razor.

**Html gets Generated as below**

```
<input class="valid" data-val="true" id="9" name="List[8].Address" onchange="ChangeEvent(this);" type="text" value="InitialValue" aria-describedby="9-error" aria-invalid="false">
```

If i set textbox value with Jquery as below:
 $('#9').val("NewValue");

[image]

Then it gets updated in the UI correctly as above

But issue as below:

```
<input class="valid" data-val="true" id="9" name="List[8].Address" onchange="ChangeEvent(this);" type="text" value="InitialValue" aria-describedby="9-error" aria-invalid="false">
```

If I right click and inspect the textbox it still shows the old value.
**value="InitialValue**

Is there any way to change this except postback?

Comment: Seems like unrelated to ASP.NET MVC, and a duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986026/html-input-is-not-updating-value-attribute-on-change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Input is not updating value attribute on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986026/html-input-is-not-updating-value-attribute-on-change)