# Obtain the value from an element inside an html table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page with a table with inputs fields in its cells and I want to jump from row to row and cell to cell to obtain that values with javascript/jquery.
I can access to the cell but I haven't found a way to access to the element inside the cell.

I tried with

```
$('#tblIssues tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)').html()
```

and it returns the html code inside my td but not the value.

The element inside the cell table can be a text area, input text or combobox. I want the value of that element.

I want to use something like a double for to go through the table and save that information into an array.

Comment: value is not an attribute

Comment: `$('#tblIssues tr:eq(1) td:eq(1) :input').val()` `:input` will match any kind of user input field.

Comment: My guess is the Issue is OP is expecting value in the HTML to be there, it does not update the attribute....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986026/html-input-is-not-updating-value-attribute-on-change

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a 2-dimensional array of values, use nested `.map()` calls to loop over the rows for the first dimension, and all the input fields for the second dimension.

Use the `.value` property of the inputs to get the current value.

```
var valArray = $.each("#tblIssues tr").map(function() {
    return $(this).find(":input").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you wish to obtain the value of input elements from within a table? and you wish to return the value for all of them separately? `html` is used to obtain to contents of an element i.e:

```js
$(function() {
$("div.header").html();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headercontainer">
<div class="header">Hello World!</div>
</div>
```

would return :

`Hello World!`

I think it would be best to look at https://api.jquery.com/html/ for more info as it can also be used to show the actual html within a container etc.

One approach to getting values for each input field would be making use a `class` that is similar for each input, you can have several classes separated by a space which can then be called upon. Something like this:

```
function Myfunc() {
var totals = 0;
$(".classa").each(function() {
totals += +$(this).val();
});
$("#total").val(totals);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
<tr>
<td>
<form>
<input type="text" class="classa classb classc" value="1" id="id1">
<input type="text" class="classa classd classe" value="2" id="id2">
<input type="text" class="classa classf classg" value="3" id="id3">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" class="button" id="getvalue" value="Add up values!" onclick="Myfunc()">
<br>
<label for="total">
<input type="text" class="total" id="total">
</label>
```

Alternatives if you wish to add text values together to make a sentence perhaps something like this would be of more interest to you :

```
function Myfunc() {
    var first = $("input.classb").val();
    var second = $("input.classd").val();
    var third = $("input.classf").val();
    var sumtext = (first + ' ' + second + ' ' + third );
    $("#totsent").val(sumtext); 
    console.log(first);
    console.log(second);
    console.log(third);
    console.log(sumtext);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
    <tr>
    <td>
    <form>
    <input type="text" class="classa classb classc" value="Hello" id="id1">
    <input type="text" class="classa classd classe" value="Beautiful" id="id2">
    <input type="text" class="classa classf classg" value="World!" id="id3">
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="button" class="button" id="getvalue" value="Add up text!" onclick="Myfunc()">
    <br>
    <label for="totsent">
    <input type="text" class="sentence" id="totsent">
    </label>
```

Maybe this answer helps, maybe it doesn't, I'm still fairly new to Jquery and JavaScript but i hope it does.

Answer (score 0):

In one line of plain JavaScript -- every value of every form field can be collected as an array.

- Wrap `<table>` in a `<form>` tag

  ```
  <form><table>...</table></form>
  ```
- Reference the form (`[0]` will target the first form tag on page)

  ```
  document.forms[0]
  ```
- Collect **[all form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements#Value)** into a HTML Collection (an array-like object)

  ```
  .elements
  ```
- Convert HTML Collection into an array

  ```
  Array.from(...)
  ```
- For every field in array return its value in a new array

  ```
  .map(field => field.value)
  ```

#### Demo

```js
const values = Array.from(document.forms[0].elements).map(field => field.value);
console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left:80%;
  overflow-y:scroll
}
.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content:'';
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<form>
<table>
  <tr><td><input value='A'></td><td><select><option value='A'>A</option><option value='B' selected>B</option><option value='C'>C</option></select></td><td><textarea>ABC</textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input value='D'></td><td><select><option value='D'>D</option><option value='E'>E</option><option value='F' selected>F</option></select></td><td><textarea>DEF</textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input value='G'></td><td><select><option value='G' selected>G</option><option value='H'>H</option><option value='I'>I</option></select></td><td><textarea>GHI</textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input value='J'></td><td><select><option value='J'>J</option><option value='K' selected>K</option><option value='L'>L</option></select></td><td><textarea>JKL</textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input value='M'></td><td><select><option value='M'>M</option><option value='N'>N</option><option value='O' selected>O</option></select></td><td><textarea>MNO</textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input value='P'></td><td><select><option value='P' selected>P</option><option value='Q'>Q</option><option value='R'>R</option></select></td><td><textarea>PQR</textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input value='S'></td><td><select><option value='S'>S</option><option value='T' selected>T</option><option value='U'>U</option></select></td><td><textarea>STU</textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input value='V'></td><td><select><option value='V'>V</option><option value='W'>W</option><option value='X' selected>X</option></select></td><td><textarea>VWX</textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input value='Y'></td><td><select><option value='Y'>Y</option><option value='Z' selected>Z</option></select></td><td><textarea>YZ</textarea></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```