# Jquery input value update confusing behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple html field

```
 <input type="text" value="#123456" name="color">
```

And basic jQuery code to change the value

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('input').val('#AAAAAA');
 });
```

**If I run this previous code, the display updates the value, but if I inspect the HTML element, it is still set to the old value**. I have to do

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('input').attr('value', '#AAAAAA');
 });
```

to actually change the input value. I was under the impression that `val()` would take care of updating the value if the input field has a `name` attribute, but it does not.
Is this expected jQuery (3.4.1) behavior ?

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3xrszny6/)

Comment: Here's a simple explanation of that behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986026/html-input-is-not-updating-value-attribute-on-change#answer-7986111

Comment: absolutely horrendous behavior, thanks for the link

Comment: attr("value", "#AAAAAA") changes the value here in the fiddle

Comment: The issue is that you have a misunderstanding of what "the value" is.  You're changing the value attribute.

Comment: adding upon @freedomn-m explanations, you may consider looking at the [`defaultValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#defaultvalue) property of an `input` element.